# Replace the floating point number in a string after multiplying it by a variable

Tags: php, math, replace, substring

I want to get the replace a number in a string after multiplying it by a variable. I have the following PHP:

```
$desc = "+2.23% critical damage";
$count = 3;`
```

Now I want to use the value of `$count * $desc` within a new string, as shown here:

`$sum = "+6.69% critical damage";`

How do I manage this? How can I multiply the numbers in this string with `$count`?

Comment: +6,69% what do you mean by this ?? your question is not clear.

Comment: 2.23 comes from a variable or is direct text?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks mate, now i got the number by using: `filter_var($desc, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION)`. But how do i filter text?

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities.

Ugly as hell, but working (use `floatval()` on the string):

```
<?php

$desc = "+2.23% critical damage";
$count = 3;
$sum = floatval($desc) * $count . "% critical damage";
echo $sum;
# 6.69% critical damage
?>
```

Second: a regex approach.

```
<?php
# define a regex to allow digits and points directly connected
$regex = '~[\d.]+~';
preg_match($regex, $desc, $num);
$sum = floatval($num[0]) * $count . "% critical damage";
echo $sum;
# 6.69% critical damage
?>
```

Third possibility (probably the best): try to refine your actual requirements and edit your question :)

Answer (score 0):

In case the rest of your string is dynamic, it may be more robust to replace the floating point number using `preg_replace_callback()` -- this way you are only touching the number in the string.

`sprintf()` is very handy for standardizing the format of the product.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Oun6R))

```
$desc = "+2.23% critical damage";
$count = 3;

var_export(
    preg_replace_callback(
        '~^[+-]\d+(?:\.\d+)?~',
        function($m) use ($count) {
            return sprintf('%+.2f', $m[0] * $count);
        },
        $desc,
        1
    )
);
```

Output:

```
'+6.69% critical damage'
```